# What does $]a,b[$ mean?

Tags: notation

I recently encountered the above notation for sets, and I've never encountered it before. What does it refer to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the notation for the open interval $(a,b)$.

Those two notations denote the same thing.

In case you do not know what an interval is, it is the set $\{x:a<x<b\}$ given an order relation $<$.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that this notation is popular in France, though not so popular in North America.

Comment: Aha! So that is why we use it in Lebanon!

Comment: It's also common in Germany, although I remember it primarily from high school. I can't say if it's frequently used in university.

Comment: Never used to use another notation here in Belgium.

Comment: $]a,b[$ has some advantages over $(a,b)$ because $(a,b)$ can mean also an ordered pair or the coordinates of a point. Also it isn't coherent in geometrical notation.

Comment: Dugundji used ]a, b[ as well as ]a, b] and [a, b[ in his topology book, which was the textbook for a course I took in the U.S.A. around 1966.

Answer (score 1):

That just means the open interval $(a,b)$. The brackets facing to the other side should indicate that the borders $a$ and $b$ do not belong to the set.

Answer (score 1):

$]a,b[$ is the set of numbers between $a$ and $b$ with $a$ and $b$ **excluded**. In symbols like Hasan Saad said $\{x:a\lt x\lt b\}$.

The opposite $[a,b]$ is the set of number between $a$ and $b$ with $a$ and $b$ **included**. In symbols $\{x:a\le x\le b\}$.